# Core Data crash with error nilOutReservedCurrentEventSnapshot

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, unrecognized-selector

I'm working on an iOS 8+ app using Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.4.
I've stumbled upon a crash error that says,

> NSCFString _nilOutReservedCurrentEventSnapshot__]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x18092960
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[**NSCFString _nilOutReservedCurrentEventSnapshot**]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x18092960

The crash occurs at a function where I create a private queue concurrency type child managed object context, and use `performBlock` to update/save certain data to core data db. At the end of the tasks, I save my parent managed object context. That is the line where it crashes.

```
moc?.save(&err)
```

Can anybody shed some light on what the error `_nilOutReservedCurrentEventSnapshot` means? I haven't found any useful resource on it yet.

Comment: I cannot see the usefulness in debugging Swift 1.2 code. Upgrade to Swift 2.0.

Comment: Not a solution for me right now as most of the libraries that i use in my project do not support Swift 2.0 yet. Anyway I don't think that is important here.

Comment: What do you mean "libraries don't support Swift 2.0"?  Swift 2.0 supports very old libraries, including ancient Objective-C.

Comment: @Mundi I mean't that few libraries that i use are written in swift 1.2, and hence they throw errors during compilation. Is there a way i can avoid that? I understand that libraries written in obj-c can be used by setting up a bridging header.

Comment: Ah, I see. What I normally do is just go through those libraries and correct them, i.e. upgrade them for Swift 2.0. myself. (That's quite a useful exercise, actually.)

Comment: @mohonish Any luck with this? I am having the same problem.